# RubyCas client using https not receiving the CasServer 'LogoutRequest'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, cas, rubycas-client

RubyCas client using https is not receiving the CasServer 'LogoutRequest'

I used 'rubyCas-client' gem. It's working fine in http (with cluster servers also), but when I am trying to use 'HTTPS' (using ssl certificate), my application server itself is not receiving the CasServer session 'LogoutRequest'. It's still maintaining the session.

Why is this happening?